# Convert Data URI using Google Apps Script Blob

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, base64

I am trying to upload and save an image from Data URI in Google Apps Script. Everything works apart from the file type being set.

I've tried all variations of newBlob as per the Apps Script documentation.

```
function doUpload(dataURI) {

var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
var type = (dataURI.split(";")[0]).replace('data:','');
var imageUpload = Utilities.base64Decode(dataURI.split(",")[1]);
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(imageUpload, type, "nameOfImage");
folder.createFile(blob);

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the small and important modification...

```
function doUpload(dataURI) {

var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
var type = (dataURI.split(";")[0]).replace('data:','');
var imageUpload = Utilities.base64Decode(dataURI.split(",")[1]);
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(imageUpload, type, "nameOfImage.png");
folder.createFile(blob);

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Converting and Saving Images as DataURI's**

I get the images from a url using UrlFetch.  If you don't have a place to host them then just put them in Google Photo Library and copy the url from there it works too.  That way you can do all your image process for web ready artwork before you convert them with standard image editors.

```
function convImageUrl(url){
  var url=url || "http://jimesteban.com/images/mimincoopers.png";
  var blob=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  var b64Url='data:' + blob.getContentType() + ';base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
  return b64Url;
}

function saveDataURIInFile(filename,datauri,type) {
  Logger.log('filename: %s\ndatauri: %s\ntype: %s\n',filename,datauri,type);
  if(filename && datauri && type) {
    var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(getGlobal('MediaFolderId'));
    var files=folder.getFilesByName(filename);
    while(files.hasNext()) {
      files.next().setTrashed(true);
    }
    var f=folder.createFile(filename,datauri,MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
    return {name:f.getName(),id:f.getId(),type:type,uri:DriveApp.getFileById(f.getId()).getBlob().getDataAsString()};
  }else{
    throw('Invalid input in saveDataURIInFile.');
  }
}
```

- [Converting Images to DataURIs Scripts](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/hot-off-the-presses/converting-images-to-datauris)
- [Converting Images to URL's Video](https://youtu.be/nqBYov-uwsQ)

Comment: Thanks Cooper but I'm trying to convert from DataURI to a blob. Think what you're showing me does the opposite? With my code I can convert to a blob and can save the file in my drive but I can't seem to set the MimeType.

Comment: If you have a datauri you can save it as plain_text.  `var f=folder.createFile(filename,datauri,MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);` as show in my example.  I have some other script in there that delete's all of the old files with the same name (actually sends them to trash).

Comment: Here's what a dataURI looks like inside: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAAMR0lEQVR42u2dbWwUxxnHTYLS0ISURrRRlCDxJkWp+qEKUtK3RHzoh5QPqSLh5mMVJVHVRiBZoY5UVcLxva8NBJOCg5EABRtjDtu8GEPqyqYFXNvY4Ffs89l39l1tn8/2nV8AGwPTnfU+x+Px7N6d70z23Bnpr73bt5ud3z7PMzO7N5OWJlJqpfb29uc9bvcfvF7vCZ/PVyWrRogvv89X3ef1Or29vZ/ScksqCL`

Comment: I'm logging my dataURI and it is the same format as that. I'm needing the files to save as jpegs but they will only save as plain text or with no file format

Comment: so I've went back to my original code (above) and the image appears on my google drive and appears to be all fine, is a jpeg etc. However, I have my google drive synced to my computer hard drive and the copy of the file on my hard drive doesn't have a file extension. Says it's a TextEdit document.

Comment: seems to work if i just append .jpg in the code! not sure if this is best practice though.

Comment: If this answered the question, you can mark it as answered by clicking the big green check mark.  If you answered your own question, then you can add your own answer.