# Embed Google Drive images in Google Apps Scripts web app is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

```
function showReviews(data) {
  var reviews = data.reviews
  var fileIds = data.starIds
  var container = document.getElementById('reviews-container');
  var reviewWidth = 100 / reviews.length + '%';

  reviews.forEach(function(review) {
    var reviewDiv = document.createElement('div');
    reviewDiv.className = 'review';
    reviewDiv.style.width = reviewWidth;
    reviewDiv.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    reviewDiv.style.height = '300px';

    // Get the corresponding star image URL
    var starImageId = fileIds[review.rating - 1];
    var starImageUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + starImageId;
    console.log (starImageUrl)
    reviewDiv.innerHTML = '<table style="width: 100%;"><tr><td><h3>' + review.author_name + '</h3>' + '<td style="text-align: left;">' + review.relative_time_description + '</td></tr>' +

                         '<tr>' +
  '<td style="text-align: left;"><img src="' + starImageUrl + '" alt="Rating: ' + review.rating + ' stars" style="height: 20px;" /></td>' +
  '<td style="text-align: left;">Rating: ' + review.rating + ' / 5</td>' +
  '</tr></table>'

 +                          '<p>' + review.text + '</p>' +
                          '<span class="read-more" onclick="toggleReview(this)">Read more</span>';
    container.appendChild(reviewDiv);
  });
}
```

This it the main function. Basically this is a web app that displays my google reviews. I have made the 1-5 stars rating images and stored them my google drive. the sharing options are set to anyone with the link. It was working perfectly for a while. But recently, I noticed all of my web apps that uses images stored in my Google Drive are not working. I used to be able to use "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + id to embed the image in the HTML. But now the image shows a broken link[how it is a broken link in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zng4J.png). But when I right clicked on the image and use "open image in a new tab" the image will display properly. [screenshot of the image in the new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKdff.png)

i have console logged the URL of the image filehttps://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1rTS4e5nJJtdUoV6GEJhIN0ZI7d98-nbg and it seems to be perfectly working fine.

I tried using different URL's to get this working and still not working. I tried logging the URL and the link seems to be ok. The method of embeding images is working well when I send emails with image using that URL

"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" +id

but still doesn't work within the GAS web app environment. I wanna know how to fix this. I tried every way possible and still can't get it to work.

Comment: [Try converting the images to dataURIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56092331/7215091)

Comment: @Raymond Huang Thank you for replying. About `first patten did work and the rest don't. The only concern is the Thumbnail may reduce the image quality is that correct?`, it's yes. In this case, I understood that my answer was not useful for your situation. I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. So, I have to delete my answer. I apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: No, that was amazing answer. Thank you for it. I don't think the quality will make too much impact to my use case. I'm sure the other two cases you mentioned were also the solutions that should work as intended. The only thing I can think of is that there were some bugs on the Google side.